# How to move jQuery object between scripts in firefox addon?

Tags: jquery, object, firefox-addon

I have a panel with script and jQuery in my addon and script which runs into page.
How do I copy object from my panel to page?

main.js

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var button = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
    id: "show-panel",
    label: "Show Panel",
    icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
    },
    onClick: handleClick
});
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    contentURL: self.data.url("page.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"), self.data.url("panel-script.js")],
    position: button
});

function handleClick() {
    panel.show();
    var worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"), self.data.url("page-script.js")]
    });
    panel.port.emit('to-panel');
    panel.port.on("from-panel", function(pic) {
        worker.port.emit("to-page", pic);
    });
}
```

panel.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="icon-64.png" class="add-img" alt="">
    <button class="click">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

panel.js

```
self.port.on("to-panel", function() {
    var pic = $('.add-img');
    $('button.click').on('click', function(){
        self.port.emit("from-panel", pic);
    });
});
```

page.js

```
self.port.on("to-page", function(pic) {
    $('body').append(pic);
});
```

I want to copy  element from my panel and place it to page.
I tried set it to variable named 'pic' and transmit to page.js for placing on webpage, but it's doesn't work. Nevertheless, the simple string is easily transmitted and placed on page.

Browser console is showing "TypeError: a is undefined".

Please help and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

`var myobjStr = JSON.stringify(myObj)` the object you have in the panel. Then its converted to string. So now pass that string to your page and then in your paste parse it like this:

`var myobjFromStr = JSON.parse(myobjStr)`

Comment: It didn't help. I forget to write, browser console is showing "TypeError: a is undefined".

Comment: Interesting, you don't have `a` anywhere in your code above so I don't know where that's coming from. But passing it as a string is the only way to pass between contexts im pretty sure.

Comment: I think I did it wrong.

`var pic = $('.add-img');
var myobjStr = JSON.stringify(pic);`

then

`var myobjFromStr = JSON.parse(myobjStr);
$('body').append(myobjFromStr);`

I can't work with this object, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Can I have something to ask you? My script in this code is executed several times, and each time pressing a button on my panel increases the number of starts. Instead one image is inserted two, then three, then four, etc. I spent the whole evening, but I can not solve this problem. Please can you help me?

Comment: Oh you cannot pass an DOM element, you can pass an object you made like `{blah:true, no:1}` but you cant `stringify` a dom element etc.

Comment: Sure I can help, do you have TeamViewer? Can you make it xpi and upload o github.

Comment: I'm newbie in creating Firefox addons and git, so here
https://github.com/through-a-haze/sandbox/blob/master/my-addon.xpi
And I haven't much time for that after a day of work, unfortunately.
So I will appreciate if you can show me my mistakes.

Comment: Well, it seems I was able to solve my problem)
Updated my github https://github.com/through-a-haze/sandbox

Comment: Awesome man!! Keep using that github! Its awesome for open source :)